# How to initialize CRT when doing LoadLibrary("*.exe")

Tags: c++, python, c, winapi, msvcrt

I am trying to pass numpy arrays to C and do some calculations there.

I am building the executable as exe and export some functions which Python then calls. The procedure works but I am unable to use standard functions like `printf()`. It works if I build the binary as a dll. From searching on the internet, I understood that the dll loading and exe loading (maincrtstartup?) do initializations for runtime libraries. Is it possible to replicate what they do so that I can use `printf()`?

Python code

```
import  numpy as np
import ctypes
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer

lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('pycon.exe')

fun = lib.fun
fun.restype = None
fun.argtypes = [ndpointer(ctypes.c_double),
                ctypes.c_size_t]



data = np.ones((5,5)).astype('double')
def wfun(d):
    fun(d, d.size)
print data
wfun(data)
print data
```

C code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) 
void fun(double *datav, size_t size) {
    //printf("crash");
    double * data = (double *) datav;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        data[i] = 1.7159*tanh(0.66666667*data[i]);
}


extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) 
void init() {
    //what to put here?
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have realized that treating an exe as a dll is far more involved than i imagined. i ended up with the following workaround.

python

```
import  numpy as np
import ctypes as C

lib = C.cdll.LoadLibrary('pycon.exe')
lib.init( C.windll.kernel32.GetProcAddress( C.windll.msvcrt._handle,'printf'))

d = np.ones((5)).astype('double')
lib.fun(d.ctypes.data_as(C.POINTER(C.c_double)), C.c_size_t(5))
```

c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int (*pyprintf)(const char *,...) =0;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) 
void fun(double *datav, size_t size) {
        double * data = (double *) datav;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            data[i] = 1.7159*tanh(0.66666667*data[i]);
            pyprintf("workign! %f\n",data[i]);
        }
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) 
void init(int (*_printfPtr)(const char *,...)) {
        pyprintf=_printfPtr;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("exe");
    return 0;
}
```

## edit

curiosity has gotten the better of me and the rabbit hole grows, now it's slightly less kludgy than above and seems to run both as exe and dll with a bit more loading code.

### requirements

- 'exe' must only have dependency on kernel32
- pefile package
- linker flags `/FIXED:NO -entry:_DllMainCRTStartup@12`

python

```
import  numpy as np
import ctypes as C
import pefile

def unprotect( address): 
    crap = C.byref(C.create_string_buffer("\x00"*4))
    res = C.windll.kernel32.VirtualProtect(address, 0x1000, 0x40, crap)

lib = C.cdll.LoadLibrary('pycon.exe')
k32 = C.windll.kernel32
pe =  pefile.PE('pycon.exe')


for entry in pe.DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT:
  #print entry.dll
  #assuming that the exe only has dependency on kernel32
  for imp in entry.imports:
    diff = imp.address-0x400000
    memptr = k32.GetProcAddress(k32._handle,imp.name)
    unprotect(lib._handle+diff)
    fptr = (C.c_uint).from_address(lib._handle+diff)
    fptr.value = memptr

d = np.ones((5)).astype('double')
lib.init()
lib.fun(d.ctypes.data_as(C.POINTER(C.c_double)), C.c_size_t(5))   
print d
```

c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>

extern "C" BOOL WINAPI  _CRT_INIT(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpReserved);

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) 
    void fun(double *datav, size_t size) {
        double * data = (double *) datav;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            data[i] = 1.7159*tanh(0.66666667*data[i]);
            printf("workign! %f\n",data[i]);
        }
        fflush(stdout);
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) 
    void init() {
        _CRT_INIT(NULL,DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH,NULL);
}


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                      DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                      LPVOID lpReserved
                      )
{
    _CRT_INIT(NULL,DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH,NULL);
    printf("main exe");
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Treating a `.exe` file as a `.dll` seems moderately ridiculous.  DLLs exist for a good reason, and they are different from EXEs for a good reason.  And the amount of work involved in 'fixing' the problems shows a large part of why trying to make one do the job of the other is ... well, if not an exercise in futility, an exercise in frustration and somewhat on the pointless side.  AFAICS, you can't run the EXE standalone; it has to be run from Python.  And that's completely counter to what an EXE is supposed to be for.